# How to run my C programs with the Bourne Shell?

Tags: sh

I have no problem running my C programs by switching to their directory and starting them with `./`. However, I'm not sure why changing to the directory and then typing `sh [Program Name]` gives me this error:

```
Fortune_Teller_5000: 1: Fortune_Teller_5000: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

and:

```
./Fortune_Teller_5000: 1: ./Fortune_Teller_5000: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I read in the bash man pages that the `sh` command is a shell that doesn't read the `.bashrc` file, so I'm a little confused as the why I can't use it to run programs I made. I did use it to install my printer drivers according to the directions on the HP Linux Imaging and Printing page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash

Comment: i assumed by the messages that the debugger in sh didn't like the program, which is confusing since bash gave me zero error messages when i compiled it

Comment: Is Fortune_Teller_5000 a C program, C source code or a shell script? You may need to clarify your question.

Comment: Can you not just copy the error but also the call?

Comment: you mean the exit status? the exit status is 2, so pretty general "error"

Comment: No, the command you are using that produce the error.

Comment: You seem to be a bit confused about the roles of the shell and a compiler.

Comment: "No, the command you are using that produce the error." I said what it was in the first paragraph. "You seem to be a bit confused about the roles of the shell and a compiler. " Duh. Try learning BASH, C programming, asembly, and general computer science all by yourself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Typing `sh program_name` assumes that **program_name** is a shell script and executes the script (so it must be in a sh/bash language).
If `Fortune_Teller_5000` is a binary file (a Compiled C program, or even C source code), running `sh Fortune_Teller_5000` will not work as expected.

Here are 2 ways you could do it:

1. Type `sh` then ENTER, and then type `./Fortune_Teller_5000` (you may need to `cd` into the proper directory)
2. Type `sh -c ./Fortune_Teller_5000` or `sh -c /path/to/folder/Fortune_Teller_5000`

Comment: all three methods worked thanks a lot. edit: oh btw, it cracks me up that with the first method it strips my color codes for the prompt string bare down to the ASCII text, so it looks hideous!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please make sure to accept my answer if this helped in resolving your problem!
Edit: yes, as you mentioned `sh` would not read `.bashrc` and so would handle colors differently, or not at all, compared to bash.

Comment: Incidentally, what sense does it make to run your C program inside another shell? You aren't using any of its features in any way, so you could simply start your program directly.

Comment: This could be used for testing under different environments where the shell is different, that's one example.

Answer (score 8):

Running `sh [Program Name]` instructs the `sh` program to execute a shell
script named `[Program Name]` so if this file is a C program, the command will fail.

The [POSX specification for sh](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html), the standard command language interpreter states that the argument for `sh` should be the “pathname of a file containing commands”.